# Is it posible to make spock specification conditional on property from Spring's application.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, spock

Background:

- project logic in Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.6.6
- some project features are conditionally available depending on specific application properties, some Spring components related with conditional features are also dependent using @ConditionalOnProperty annotation on component
- tests (also integration) are written in groovy and spock framework (ver. 2.1-groovy-3.0)

Question:
Is it posible to make spock specification conditional on property from spring's application.properties?

Spock framework provides annotations which make test conditional.
Most accurate seems to be @Requires for my case.
(https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_requires)
Condition is based on PreconditionContext (https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#precondition_context).

Simplified Specificatiotion example (two working @Requires annotations left as example, but they do not check what is needed in my case):

```
import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.PreconditionContext
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import spock.lang.Requires
import spock.lang.Specification
    
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles('integration')
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestSpringBootApplication)
//TODO: How to make this feature dependent of property from application.properties?
//@Requires(reason = 'Specification for AAA feature enabled', value = { isFeatureAAAEnabled() })
//@Requires(reason = 'Test run only on Linux', value = { PreconditionContext preconditionContext -> preconditionContext.os.windows })
class ConditionalSpec extends Specification {

    //Some conditional components @Autowired

    //feature methods
    def "one plus one should equal two"() {
        expect:
        1 + 1 == 2
    }

    private static boolean isFeatureAAAEnabled() {
        true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want exactly, is it enough to just not run any tests but still start the spring context, or do you want to also avoid starting the spring context?

If it is the first one, then you can use `instance` or `shared` from the [Precondition Context](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/extensions.html#precondition_context). If you enable [shared field injection](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/module_spring.html#_shared_fields_injection) you should be able to do this.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles('integration')
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestSpringBootApplication)
@EnableSharedInjection
@Requires(reason = 'Specification for AAA feature enabled', value = { shared.myValue == 'featureAAA' })
class ConditionalSpec extends Specification {

    @Value('${value.from.file}')
    @Shared
    String myValue

    //feature methods
    def "one plus one should equal two"() {
        expect:
        1 + 1 == 2
    }
}
```

If you can't use shared injection due to it's limitations, then you'll have to replace `shared` by `instance` in the condition.

---

If you want to avoid starting spring, then you'll have to write [your own extension](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/extensions.html#_writing_custom_extensions) to figure out what the value from the `application.properties`, and skip the spec yourself.

Comment: Initialization of Spring context is OK as long as works properly concerning conditional components (declared with @ConditionalOnProperty).
Shared property in @Requires as you proposed with @Autowired(required=false) for injected beans used the conditional Specification seems to be solution in my case.